# Equivalent subset relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Textbook and online resources say something along the following lines:

> $R$ is the *subset relation* where $(A, B) \in R$ if and only if $A, B \subseteq C$ and $A \subseteq B$.

Is this also equivalent to

> $R$ is the *subset relation* where $(A, B) \in R$ if and only if $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$.

I think they are, but I haven't come across any that states the definition in the latter way.

I have tried a making up a few sets $A, B, C$ such that $A, B \subseteq C$ and $A \subseteq B$. So far, all of them also satisfy $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$.

Comment: You're assuming that $B \subset C$ and $A \subset B$ in either case. They are exactly the same.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how $C$ fits into the definition (is $C$ a universal superset?) but the statement 1) $A\subset C$, $B \subset C$ and $A\subset B$.  and statement 2) $A \subset B \subset C$ are *exactly* the same thing.  If statement 1) then $A \subset B$ and $B \subset C$ so that means $A \subset B \subset C$... or statement 2.  Is statement 2) If $A \subset B$ and $B \subset $ then it follows that $A \subset C$  ... so statement 1.

Comment: I *think* what is going on is that to define *any* relationship between subsets of $C$ it is understood that $A, B \subset C$ because that is the "universe" we are talking about.  We are only talking about relationships between two subsets $A,B$ of $C$.  The relationship itself is that $A \subset B$.  Since $B \subset C$ this is simply the same thing as stating $A \subset B \subset C$.  Conversely, if you have a statement $A \subset B\subset C$ the we know $A \subset C$ that can be inferred, but it goes without saying.

Comment: @fleablood I copied the first snippet directly from the textbook. $C$ does seem to be a universal superset

Comment: I wouldn't lose sleep over this.  But for thouroughness sake, could you give a reference to the textbook, and a reference to the site that defined things otherwise?

Comment: To get pedantic, an relationship *on* a set X, requires a set X so that the relation $R$ is a set of ordered pairs $\{(a,b)\}$ where $a , b \in X$ and $a R b$.  It sounds like in this case $X$ is presumed to be $P(C)$, the power set of $C$, or the set of all subsets.  So A R B is a relationship where $A,B \subset C$ and $A$ and $B$ are related.  The way in which the are related is that $A \subset B$.  These two definitions are exactly the same, but they are expressed in slightly different frames of reference.